# Python undetectable_webdriver won't open in a loop

Tags: python, selenium, loops, selenium-chromedriver, undetected-chromedriver

I am trying to open a site multiple times in a loop to test if different credentials have expired so that I can notify our users. I'm achieving this by opening the database, getting the records, calling the chrome driver to open the site, and inputting the values into the site. The first loop works but when the next one initiates the driver hangs and eventually outputs the error:

```
  "unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:XXXX from chrome not reachable"
```

This error commonly occurs when there is already an instance running. I have tried to prevent this by using both driver.close() and driver.quit() when the first loop is done but to no avail. I have taken care of all other possibilities of detection such as using proxies, different user agents, and also using the undetected_chromedriver by https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver.

The core issue I am looking to solve is being able to open an instance of the chrome driver, close it and open it back again all in the same execution loop until all the credentials I am testing have finished. I have abstracted the code and provided an isolated version that replicates the issue:

```
# INSTALL CHROMDRIVER USING "pip install undetected-chromedriver"
import undetected_chromedriver.v2 as uc

# Python Libraries
import time

options = uc.ChromeOptions()

options.add_argument('--no-first-run')

driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)

length = 8
count = 0
if count < length:
    print("Im outside the loop")
    while count < length:
        print("This is loop ",count)
        time.sleep(2)
        with driver:
            print("Im inside the loop")
            count =+ 1
            driver.get("https://google.com")
            time.sleep(5)
            print("Im at the end of the loop")
            driver.quit()   # Used to exit the browser, and end the session
            # driver.close()  # Only closes the window in focus
```

I recommend using a python virtualenv to keep packages consistent. I am using python3.9 on a Linux machine. Any solutions, suggestions, or workarounds would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are quitting your driver in the loop and then trying to access the executor address, which no longer exists, hence your error. You need to reinitialize the driver by moving it down within the loop, before the while statement.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, freeze_support
import undetected_chromedriver as uc

# Python Libraries
import time

chroptions = uc.ChromeOptions()

chroptions.add_argument('--no-first-run enable_console_log = True')
# driver = uc.Chrome(options=chroptions)

length = 8
count = 0
if count < length:
    print("Im outside the loop")
    while count < length:
        print("This is loop ",count)
        driver = uc.Chrome(options=chroptions)
        time.sleep(2)
        with driver:
            print("Im inside the loop")
            count =+ 1
            driver.get("https://google.com")
            print("Session ID: ", end='')  #added to show your session ID is changing
            print(driver.session_id)
            driver.quit()
```